# Pass checkbox values to laravel controller for deleting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with checkbox

```
<form action="{{url("/del")}}" method="post">
<td><input   type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="@{{row.DataID}}"></td>
<button type="submit" name="bulk_delete" id="bulk_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</button>
```

How to pass checked box array values to the controller for deleting.

controller.

```
public function del(Request $request )
    {

     DB::table('master')->delete();

     return redirect ("/works")->with("Success","Deleted Successfully") ;
    }
```

Comment: debug and print_r `$request ` object you will get posted data

Comment: is this in foreach ? many buton or single button ? show more details ?

Comment: this is in angular repeat. only one button for delete @Hamelraj

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
<form action="{{url("/del")}}" method="post">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="@{{row.DataID}}">
    </td>
    <button type="submit" name="bulk_delete" id="bulk_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

**In Controller**

```php
public function del(Request $request )
{
   $idsArry  = $request->delid;
   DB::table('master')->whereIn('id', $idsArry)->delete(); 
   return redirect ("/works")->with("Success","Deleted Successfully") ;
}
```

Comment: Showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: @TestCheck where is you forech above answer does not contain foreach please check this is other error

Comment: I changed the code to  $idsArry  = $request->input ('delid',[]);
   DB::table('master')->whereIn('id', $idsArry)->delete();     Now not getting the error.  but not deleting the rows